# TestCafe Browser Tools Keeps requesting to Screen Record

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

TestCafe keeps requesting to screen record, even though the checkbox is clicked in systems preferences. I have removed, readded, clicked and unclicked many times the checkbox, but it keeps asking...

`TestCafe requires permission to record the screen. Open 'System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Screen Recording' and check 'TestCafe Browser Tools' in the application list`

I have removed and added back the tools and also unclicked and clicked the checkmark.[image]

Comment: IME testcafe is full of bugs. Use protractor instead

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version, there's a couple of things you can do.

Newer (v1.18+):
Follow the [upgrade instructions here](https://testcafe.io/403664/release-notes/framework/2021-12-22-testcafe-v1-18-0-released#upgrade-instructions). Essentially remove the Browser Tools completely (highlighting, then clicking the - symbol), and go to your home directory. Display hidden folders, and select the browser tools option within `~/.testcafe-browser-tools`

Older (pre v1.18):
There's a few solutions proposed within [this thread](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6198), but essentially you can remove the browser tools, and then run testcafe as `sudo`, re-adding, or grant permission to `node_modules/testcafe-browser-tools/bin/mac/TestCafe Browser Tools.app`